# Scipy equivalent of numpy where for sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am looking for an equivalent of [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to be used with the sparse representations that scipy offers ([`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)).
Is there anything that lets you deal with those matrices as if you where using an if-then-else statement?

***UPDATE***
To be more specific: I need `where` as an if-then-else vectorialized function, i.e. in tasks like, for each value that equals K in matrix A, put a corresponding value in matrix B, else C.
You could use something like `find` to retrieve the indexes of those entries that satisfy the logical condition, then negate them to find all the remaining ones, but for sparse matrices, isn't there a more compact way?

Comment: What do you know about the sparsity of `A==k`, `B`, `C`?  If `A==k` is quite sparse, then `A!=k` would be nearly dense.  It might give you a  `SparseEfficiencyWarning`.

Comment: It could be possible, however I believe this is not the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that duplicates `np.where`, when `cond`, `x`, and `y` are matching sized sparse matrices.

```
def where1(cond, x):
    # elements of x where cond
    row, col, data = sparse.find(cond) # effectively the coo format
    data = np.ones(data.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
    zs = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=cond.shape)
    xx = x.tocsr()[row, col][0]
    zs.data[:] = xx
    zs = zs.tocsr()
    zs.eliminate_zeros()
    return zs

def where2(cond, y):
    # elements of y where not cond
    row, col, data = sparse.find(cond)
    zs = y.copy().tolil() # faster for this than the csr format
    zs[row, col] = 0
    zs = zs.tocsr()
    zs.eliminate_zeros()
    return zs

def where(cond, x, y):
    # like np.where but with sparse matrices
    ws1 = where1(cond, x)
    # ws2 = where1(cond==0, y) # cond==0 is likely to produce a SparseEfficiencyWarning
    ws2 = where2(cond, y)
    ws = ws1 + ws2
    # test against np.where
    w = np.where(cond.A, x.A, y.A)
    assert np.allclose(ws.A, w)
    return ws

m,n, d = 100,90, 0.5
cs = sparse.rand(m,n,d)
xs = sparse.rand(m,n,d)
ys = sparse.rand(m,n,d)
print where(cs, xs, ys).A
```

Even after figuring out how to code `where1`, it took further thought to figure out a way to apply the `not` side of the problem without generating a warning.  Its not as general or fast as  the dense `where`, but it illustrates the complexity that's involved in building sparse matrices this way.

It's worth noting that

```
np.where(cond) == np.nonzero(cond) # see doc

xs.nonzero() == (xs.row, xs.col) # for coo format
sparse.find(xs) == (row, col, data)
```

`np.where` with x and y is equivalent to:

```
[xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in zip(condition,x,y)]  # see doc
```

The C code probably implements this with an `nditer`, which is functionally like `zip`, stepping through all the elements of the inputs and output.  If the output is anywhere close to dense (e.g. `y=2`), then the `np.where` will be faster than this sparse substitute.

Answer (score 7):

You could use scipy.sparse.find (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html).
This function returns the non-negative values of a sparse matrix. 
For a certain condition you could use i.e.:

```
 import scipy.sparse as sp
 A = sp.csr_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 5]])
 B = A > 2 #the condition
 indexes = sp.find(B)
```

Comment: `find` is not the same as `where`, that lets you do more complex operations even on different matrices

Comment: So `find` isn't the same, but can it be used to do what you want?  Maybe you should edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my replacement of [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) for sparse matrices using [find](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html):

```
def where(mask, val, arr):
    """ Sparse `where` """
    out = arr.copy()
    rows, cols, _ = find(mask)
    for r, c in zip(rows, cols):
        out[r, c] = val
    return out
```