# How to map scipy.sparse.lil_array?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a starting `lil_array` of boolean values. ([Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_array.html))

Eg dimensions 3,5 and values:

```
  (0, 2)    True
  (0, 4)    True
  (1, 0)    True
  (1, 1)    True
  (1, 3)    True
  (2, 0)    True
  (2, 3)    True
```

So this graphically is a matrix like the following (True represented as 1):

```
0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0
```

I also have a np.ndarray of the same size as the rows filled with Int values.
For this example I will use the following:

```
arr = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3, 2])
```

I want to produce the following lil_array (zeroes will not be saved in the sparse of course):

```
0  0  0  0  2
0 -1  0  3  0
0  0  0  3  0
```

where each row is the logical and of the initial lil_array corresponding row and `arr`.

I know how to do this in several ways transforming the lil_array into a matrix first or the rows into ndarrays or lists but this would loose the efficiency gained by exploiting the sparse property of this matrix. (This is a toy example but my problem involves a way bigger matrix)

How can I produce the output in an efficient and clean way without turning the sparse into a matrix?

Comment: There appears to have been a problem with your cut-and-paste of the `arr = ...` line.  Even assuming you meant `arr = np.ndarray(...)`.  That fails because the first argument to `np.ndarray` is the shape.

Comment: Was probably a typo, missing a 'y'. All good now? @Malcolm

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have edited my message under you.  `arr = np.ndarray([0, -1, 0, 3, 2])` fails with `ValueError: negative demensions are not allowed`.

Comment: Don't you just want `arr = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3, 2])`?

Comment: @Malcolm yes thank you, now the question is better formulated

Comment: Do you have to store your original booleans as a lil_array?  Could you just store it as a series of tuples that correspond to the true values?

Comment: Unfortunately, I really need to use lil_array, it's a mandatory requrement (I myself would have ditched it ages ago)

Comment: Show your logic using just numpy arrays.  At the moment trying to mix dense and sparse is too confusing.

Comment: @hpaulj You can ditch the numpy array and use a list if you like, but I Need the sparse

Comment: I want to see your logic using `lilmat.to_array()`.  But why `lil`, as opposed to `csr` or `coo`?  Have you looked at the `data` and `rows` attributes of you `lil`?

Comment: The example I produced is to exemplify a more complex problem part of a larger project in which the choice of `lil_array` was not made by me and I cannot change @hpaulj. Actually in this example I produced some values but I don't know in advance the density of the matrix (which is however always quite sparse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would steer you away from lil_array if your primary concern is memory efficiency. LIL uses lists internally, and lists in Python [are not very memory efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50113269/530160). lil_array is mainly useful if you want to create a sparse array but don't know how many non-zero elements it will have. I would steer you toward COO or CSR instead.

Second, what you're looking for is essentially `np.where(boolean_array, arr, 0)`, with the exception that you want it to work on sparse arrays without converting them to non-sparse arrays first.

Some googling for "scipy sparse where" finds [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145253/scipy-equivalent-of-numpy-where-for-sparse-matrices), which is almost the code we need.

The `where1` function is almost what we need, except that it assumes that the second array it's indexing into is a 2D sparse array, when what you have is a 1D dense array. We can fix that by removing the calls to `.tocsr()`, and indexing by column only.

Code:

```
def where1(cond, x):
    assert len(x.shape) == 1, "x should be 1d"
    # elements of x where cond
    row, col = cond.nonzero()
    data = np.empty(row.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
    zs = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=cond.shape)
    xx = x[col]
    zs.data[:] = xx
    zs.eliminate_zeros()
#     zs = zs.tolil()
    return zs
```

(Uncomment `zs = zs.tolil()` if you want the result in lil.)

According to a benchmark, this is about 100x faster than @Malcolm's answer for a 100000x10000 matrix with 0.1% nonzero elements.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for, I will read it a couple times to make sure I get it before marking as accepted but this seems great work!

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest NOT storing your original array as a lil_array.  Instead just store the list of tuples that correspond to the true values.  Or if you already have it as a lil_array, then converting that to a list of indices using the `lil_array.nonzero` method.
Then use those tuples to fill values in a lil_array as your result.

```
>>> x = lil_array((3,5), dtype=bool)
>>> x[0,2] = True
>>> x[0,4] = True
>>> x[1,0] = True
>>> x[1,1] = True
>>> x[1,3] = True
>>> x[2,0] = True
>>> x[2,3] = True
>>> arr = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3, 2])
>>> nz = x.nonzero()
>>> result = lil_array((3,5), dtype=int)
>>> for i, j in zip(nz[0], nz[1]):
...     result[i, j] = arr[j]
... 
>>> print(result)
  (0, 4)    2
  (1, 1)    -1
  (1, 3)    3
  (2, 3)    3
>>> print(result.toarray())
[[ 0  0  0  0  2]
 [ 0 -1  0  3  0]
 [ 0  0  0  3  0]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest code - if the sparse matrix is actually dense

```
In [42]: mat=[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    ...: [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    ...: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
    ...: #I also have a np.ndarray of the same size as the rows filled with Int values. For this example I will use the following:
    ...: 
    ...: arr = np.array([0, -1, 0, 3, 2])

In [43]: mat = np.array(mat)

In [44]: np.where(mat, arr, 0)
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  3,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  3,  0]])
```

If the matrix is not too large (i.e. no memory errors), it's easy to convert to and from sparse and dense:

```
In [45]: from scipy import sparse    
In [46]: M = sparse.lil_matrix(mat)    
In [47]: M
Out[47]: 
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 7 stored elements in List of Lists format>    
In [48]: print(M)
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 4)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  (1, 1)    1
  (1, 3)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (2, 3)    1
```

dense as I started:

```
In [49]: M.A
Out[49]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Note that usually `lil` is used construct a matrix iteratively.  `coo` format is better for constructing from the coordinates as shown in [48].  And `csr` is best for calculations.  `sparse` converts among these alternatives easily.  (The `toarray()` is normally created via a csr format).

The lil values are stored as two object dtype arrays - each containing lists representing each row:

```
In [50]: M.data, M.rows
Out[50]: 
(array([list([1, 1]), list([1, 1, 1]), list([1, 1])], dtype=object),
 array([list([2, 4]), list([0, 1, 3]), list([0, 3])], dtype=object))
```

Again that format is easy to modify iteratively, but isn't the most compact or computionally convenient.

On a further edit I'll explore working from `M` to create the mapping you want.  While it's easy to iterate on the rows of `M` (there's even a `getrowview`), the logical and between the rwo and `arr` isn't obvious.

Here's a way of iterating on the rows of the lil

```
In [51]: M = sparse.lil_matrix(mat)
    ...: for i in range(3):
    ...:     M.data[i] = arr[M.rows[i]].tolist()
    ...: M.A
Out[51]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  3,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  3,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

In other words, use the `rows` list to index `arr`, and assign those values (as list) back to `M`.

Since `arr` has some 0 values, those will appear in the new `M`:

```
    ...: M.data
Out[52]: array([list([0, 2]), list([0, -1, 3]), list([0, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Getting rid of those 0s requires pruning the `rows` attribute as well.

It's also possible to iterate on the rows of the `csr` format.  It's likely to be faster, though conceptually it's more complicated.